# How to fetch paypal transaction details from url?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have done a PayPal transaction, payment was successful and redirected to my page. But I need the transaction details should be visible on my page. how to do that? It said use **Instant Payment Notification** but I didn't get an idea how to use that to fetch details from URL.

Comment: Have you checked the API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can get transaction details from paypal after successful payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549964/how-can-get-transaction-details-from-paypal-after-successful-payment)